# Currently open questions that would not require infinite memory to evaluate computationally

Tags: big-list, open-problem

I was reading an [old thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97004/does-the-code-terminate) over at the code golf / code challenge Stack Exchange, which asks users to come up with a computer program for which it is an open question whether it terminates.

My first thought was that one would have to assume the computer has infinite memory, because for example, if you want to look for odd perfect numbers then sooner or later you will reach integers whose binary representation is too large for a finite amount of memory.

But I wonder if that's necessarily the case. Perhaps there are open questions that could be determined computationally without infinite memory, because (for example) they involve checking all the permutations of some finite sequence, such that it would take an extremely long *time* to check computationally, while having a known bound on the amount of space.

So formally, I suppose I'm asking for a Turing machine for which it is known that it will never leave a particular bounded region of its tape (and those bounds are known), but it is not known whether or not it halts. I'm fine with informal answers though.

(I suppose a technically correct answer would be "are there any odd perfect numbers less than $10^{2000}$?", but this is kind of cheating - I'm looking for answers where the bound on memory is a natural part of the conjecture, rather than just set above the current known bound.)

Comment: If a turing machine is known to never leave a particular region of the tape, it can always be determined whether this turing machine halts. If it does not, it must eventually repeat a configuration and then we can conclude that it can never halt.

Comment: @Peter the point here is that the time between repeating configurations can be arbitrarily long, and it's not hard to construct examples where it's vastly higher than the lifetime of the Universe. So while "it can always be determined" is true in principle given unlimited computational resources, it can still be an open problem in practice.

Comment: Then, please clarify what you actually want! Of course, a problem that is decidable in theory need not be decidable in practice.

Comment: @Peter what I want are problems that are decidable in theory but are not currently decided in practice. But I am looking for a specific subset of such problems, namely those for which (i) there is a known bound on how much memory would be required to decide some particular instance of the problem, and (ii) that particular instance is a notable open question in mathematics.

Comment: A currently open problem that is definitely decidable wth a finite amount of time and space is whether the $33$-rd Fermat number $F_{33}=2^{(2^{33})}+1$ is a prime number. It will take long to decide this, unless someone finds a factor.

Comment: @Peter fair enough, it's not a bad example. I'm hoping, ideally, for examples that don't contain a numerical parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I nominate the first [Skewes' number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number), defined as the smallest positive integer such that [$\pi(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\gt$ [$\operatorname{li}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). The number has been proved to exist, and upper bounds have been successively refined down to $\simeq 10^{316}$ but ["*there is no explicit value x known for certain to have the property π(x) > li(x)*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number#More_recent_estimates) yet.

Comment: Wish the serial downvoter had left a comment why.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for nontrivial uncomputable functions. For that, I recommend exploring the [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver); it is uncomputable, but it is possible to explore all possible permutations of Turing machines at some of the lower-ended state counts to see which one produces the maximal number of 1's. Hence, we've found the numerical values of $\Sigma(3)$ and $\Sigma(4)$, but not $\Sigma(5)$. Any Turing machine solution to $\Sigma(n)$ must necessarily halt and use a finite amount of memory, but actually determining whether any arbitrary $n$-state Turing machine halts is... well, uncomputable.

So in that sense, it is an open conjecture that $\Sigma(5) = 4098$, and proving or disproving it would not take an infinite amount of memory- just some assumptions regarding the lack-of-termination of some Turing machine configurations.

Comment: Actually this isn't quite what I'm looking for. The conjecture that $\Sigma(5)=4098$ is equivalent to the conjecture that some set of Turing machines don't halt (specifically, the set of all other 5-state Turing machines that print at least 4098 1's). But there is no program that can be run to verify this, let alone one with a known bound on its memory usage. You're right that the problem becomes trivial if we throw in the *assumption* that none of those machines halt --- but without *proving* it, we don't know whether that assumption is true.

Comment: Ah, so you're specifically looking for computable problems where the computation is just too costly to actually carry out?

Comment: Yes! (And specifically, ones that are computable with a known bound on the memory required to perform the computation. They have to be notable mathematical conjectures also.)